# Goldstine's Theorem, why is $\Phi$ surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am refering to this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstine_theorem

Why is $\Phi:X\to\mathbb{C}^n$, $x\mapsto (\phi_1(x),\dots,\phi_n(x))$ surjective?

Is it because of dimension reasons? ($X$ is infinite dimension, while $\mathbb{C}^n$ is finite dimensional?)

Comment: It follows from the assumption that the $\phi_i$ are linearly independent

Comment: @carucel can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We establish a contrapositive. Notice that $\Phi$ is linear. Hence if $\Phi$ is not surjective, its image must lie in some hyperplane $c_1 z_1 + \dotsb + c_n z_n = 0$. This means that $c_1 \phi_1 (x) + \dotsb + c_n \phi_n(x) = 0$ for all $x \in X$, which is precisely the definition of $c_1 \phi_1 + \dotsb + c_n \phi_n = 0$.

Comment: Is it ok to say that since the $\phi_i$ are linearly independent, so dimension of $\Phi(X)=n=\dim C^n$ thus it is surjective?

Comment: Might just be my limitation, but I can't say I follow that argument. I'd need more details.